# Echoing the data from data array passed to view in code igniter

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, frameworks

So I'm trying to echo specific values from the array, but I get message:

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/drilldown.php
Line Number: 92
```

that many times.

Heres the result of print_r of the array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [productCode] => S10_1949 [productName] => 1952 Alpine Renault 1300 [productLine] => Classic Cars [productScale] => 1:10 [productVendor] => Classic Metal Creations [productDescription] => Turnable front wheels; steering function; detailed interior; detailed engine; opening hood; opening trunk; opening doors; and detailed chassis. [quantityInStock] => 7305 [buyPrice] => 98.58 [MSRP] => 214.3 [image] => S10_1949.jpg ) )
```

View Code:

```
$follow = $p['0'];
foreach($follow as $item) {
echo $item->productCode;
```

}

Model Code:

```
  public function getProduct($p)
 {
 $this->db->where('productCode', $p);
 $resultset = $this->db->get('products');
return $resultset->result_array();
 }
```

Controller Code:

```
 function drillDown()


 {
        $productID=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['p']=$this->littlemodel->getProduct($productID);
        $this->load->view('drillDown',$data);
    }
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Wich is Line number 92?

Comment: line number 92 is where I try to echo the value echo $item->productCode;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just want one row from the database.
You should be using

```
return $resultset->row()
```

So in the model, try this:

```
public function getProduct($p)
{
    $this->db->where('productCode', $p);
    return $this->db->get('products')->row();
}
```

Keep the controller code the same.

In the view, use this:

```
echo $p->productCode;
```

This is just an optimized way of fetching your requirements. In case of any trouble, do let me know. Will be happy to help.